# Modify function to output and save list

Tags: python, function, file-management

I am trying to return a list of unit numbers from about 1000 csv file names. I can read them in then get python to remove all the junk from around them and replace the 5th character to format it how I need it done. I would like to return a list of all the unit numbers so like ['6726-0501', '6826-1144']. What I am currently getting is it printing out the unit number one by one and not saving them. I have looked through previous questions but can't seem to get the mode of creating a list then appending the unit numbers to the list and saving that list to a variable to work. Does anyone know a good method for simply modifying this to output a list and save the list for later use?

Thanks,

Robin

```
file_names = ['job_1106_unit_672600501_las_PN23074.LAS.csv', 'job_1108_unit_682601144_las_PN23072.LAS.csv']


def change(file_names):
    for comps in file_names:
         comps_of_comps = list(comps)
         unit_num = comps_of_comps[14:23] #[672600501]
         a = (unit_num[0:4])  #[6726]
         b = (unit_num[5:9])   #[0501]
         unit_num = a + list('-') + b  #[6,7,2,6,-,0,5,0,1]
         unit_num = ''.join(unit_num) #6726-0501
         print unit_num

change(file_names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a new list and append to it and return that list. Like

```
file_names = ['job_1106_unit_672600501_las_PN23074.LAS.csv', 'job_1108_unit_682601144_las_PN23072.LAS.csv']
def change(file_names):
    result = []
    for comps in file_names:
         comps_of_comps = list(comps)
         unit_num = comps_of_comps[14:23] #[672600501]
         a = (unit_num[0:4])  #[6726]
         b = (unit_num[5:9])   #[0501]
         unit_num = a + list('-') + b  #[6,7,2,6,-,0,5,0,1]
         unit_num = ''.join(unit_num) #6726-0501
         result.append(unit_num)
    return result

print change(file_names)
```

OR

```
import re

def change(file_names):
    result = []
    for i in file_names:
        s = re.match('.*unit_(.*)_las.*', i).group(1)
        result.append(s[:len(s)/2]+"-"+s[(len(s)/2)+1:])
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks I went with the first option and that worked perfectly. I appreciate your help.